# Symfony Panther - Rollback db transaction in functional test

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony-panther

I want to rollback all queries made inside the symfony/panther test.

With the normal WebTestCase i can achieve that by

```
protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->client = static::createClient();
    $this->client->disableReboot();
    $this->connection = $this->client->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getConnection();
    $this->connection->beginTransaction();
    $this->connection->setAutoCommit(false);
}
protected function tearDown()
{
    parent::tearDown();
    if ($this->connection->isTransactionActive()) {
        $this->connection->rollback();
    }
}
```

How to achieve the same with [Panther](https://github.com/symfony/panther) since there is no `$client->disableReboot()` method?

Comment: Your tests should not use database connection at all. If database is down, tests will not work, also think about development environments.

Comment: I think it's not that bad to use a real db for functional tests -> https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html#changing-database-settings-for-functional-tests